# smoothdivscroll.com jquery slider not working

Tags: jquery, html

I'd like to use the jquery found on this site, but can't find the reason it is not working on [my site](http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/). I am a designer, not a developer.

I have the following code:

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript"> $(document).ready(function () { $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({ mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections", manualContinuousScrolling: true, autoScrollingMode: "onStart" }); }); </script> 
</head>

<div id="makeMeScrollable">
  <div class="scrollingHotSpotLeft" style="display: block; opacity: 0;"></div>
  <div class="scrollingHotSpotRight" style="opacity: 0;"></div>
  <div class="scrollWrapper">
    <div class="scrollableArea" style="width: 3784px;">
      <img src="http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/lenders-01.jpg" alt="Accreditations" id="Accreditations1" /><img src="http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/lenders-02.jpg" alt="Accreditations" id="Accreditations2" /><img src="http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/lenders-03.jpg" alt="Accreditations" id="Accreditations3" /><img src="http://test.doig.com.au/meyer/wp-content/uploads/2016/02/lenders-04.jpg" alt="Accreditations" id="Accreditations4" /></div>
  </div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#makeMeScrollable").smoothDivScroll({
            mousewheelScrolling: "allDirections",
            manualContinuousScrolling: true,
            autoScrollingMode: "onStart"
        });
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got the solution of your problem,

You forget to link other js files after your `jquery.min.js`

```
   <script src="js/jquery-ui-1.10.3.custom.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mousewheel.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.kinetic.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<!-- Smooth Div Scroll 1.3 minified-->
<script src="js/jquery.smoothdivscroll-1.3-min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Dont forget to write your correct project path to these js files.

Another problem is you forget to upload a file name `layers.framework.js` in following path:

```
wp-content/themes/layerswp/assets/js/layers.framework.js
```

Comment: Thanks @saadeez. I've followed your advice, and ensured all the js files are there, but now the slider has disappeared. Can't see why.

Comment: @Steve - Also try to add smoothdivscroll's CSS file name "smoothDivScroll.css" & link this CSS file on your Head tags.

Comment: Thanks @sadeez. Done that, now the slider has disappeared. :(

Comment: @Steve - Glad your slider is now showing & working on my browser, try adding some CSS on file `smoothDivScroll.css` on line # 4 change height to `height: auto` & try to use all separate logo images.

Comment: Also add in your `style.css` file the following CSS `story .scrollableArea img { max-width:none; width:auto; display: inline-block; }`

Comment: You beauty! Thank you so much @saadeez. Life saver.

Comment: Your welcome @Steve, I will be appreciate if you please award bounty by clicking on " +50 " on left voting section. :)

Comment: Done. Great persistence!

Answer (score 0):

you are forget to close });  Please check below code

```
 <script>
  // <![CDATA[
  $('#Submitgo').on('click', function () { var url =  $('#dynamic_select').val(); window.location = url; alert(url); 

  });
  // ]]>;
 </script>
```

Comment: replace all $ sign with jQuery